# builtin 'Laravel Class not found' in fresh installation

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing, adobe-brackets

I am trying to learn laravel and hence downloaded it via composer. Somewhere on YouTube a guy started with 'route.php' file, so I just followed him but on the contrary, I faced an error on browser i.e. " **Fatal error: Class 'Route' not found in C:\wamp\www\php\lara\app\routes.php on line 14**". This error shows '**Call Stack**' along '**Time**', '**Memory**', '**Function**', '**Location**' fields. when I switch to other adjecent file i.e. Filters.php, it shows same error with class 'app' instead of 'route'. . After that, if i switch to 'public' folder and 'index.php', It shows laravel logo. I am using Brackets with live preview.Now I searched about it but not much replies to queries, if any.

in case you need more detail of this file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

**Note**: if I don't use Brackets' live preview and rather just move to 'localhost/php/lara/app/' it doesn't show any error rather a blank page with other folder i.e. 'Commands', 'Config', 'Controllers' etc.
I just don't know what to do as its my very first attempt to any MVC FRAMEWORK FOR PHP. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that autoload file is missing. Did you install Laravel using composer? If you did, try to regenerate autoload file by running following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

If you didn't install it with composer follow Laravel docs http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#installation

Comment: @Giedrius  I did both i.e. composer dump-autoload, update. but nothing.